# WPML if ( ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE==('en' or 'es') not working

Tags: php, translation, wpml

I am using WPML on my site and I am using the `ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE==` to change what appears in one template depending on the language. At the moment if the language is english something shows, if it is any other language nothing shows.  I wanted to change the logic so that the content shows in english or Spanish so I changed:

```
( ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE=='en' )
```

to:

`( ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE==('en' or 'es')` .

This does not work - it prints the content for every language not just english and spanish. I tried adding the `( ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE=='es' )` as an elseif statement but that didn't do the job either. I am wondering if some of my basic syntax is wrong in the original code - see below.  Any ideas about what I am doing wrong?

```
if ( ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE=='en' ) {?>
        <?php do_action( 'tt_single_property_content_before' ); ?>
        <?php echo apply_filters( 'the_content', get_post_field( 'post_content', $single_property_id ) ); ?>
        <?php do_action( 'tt_single_property_content_after' ); ?>
    </section>
<?php} else { }
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should change

```
if ( ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE=='en' ) {?>
```

to:

```
if ((ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE=='en') OR (ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE=='es')) {?>
```